# How to use .Net Core with Openssl3 on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, .net-core, openssl, rider

I am using Aes.Gcm encryption but it seems it is not supported by default OpenSSL version on Mac OS and I am getting following error:

```
 System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Algorithm 'AesGcm' is not supported on this platform.
```

So I installed OpenSSL 3 with `brew instal openssl` and as suggested by homebrew I ran:

```
$ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/user/.bash_profile
```

No when I type `openssl version` in terminal I get:

```
OpenSSL 3.0.1 14 Dec 2021 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.1 14 Dec 2021)
```

However I don't know how to force .Net Core to use this OpenSSL version. I am getting same error so I suppose .Net does not know which OpenSSL to load (the default one is still there - `LibreSSL 2.8.3`. It's just overwritten by PATH in .bash_profile).

How I can tell .Net compiler (or runtime?) to load OpenSSL v3?
I am using `net6.0` and Jetbrains Rider IDE (maybe I can set Openssl version / path in IDE somehow).

Comment: .NET Core migrated to macOS native crypto a long while ago, so not using openssl ever since, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit/ If you indeed need to consume openssl, you have to use a managed wrapper yourself.

Comment: Maybe you can consume `System.Security.Crypography.OpenSsl` directly, https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/libraries/System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to point the runtime to the location of the OpenSSL binaries using environment variables.

To get things working from your IDE, try adding something like the following to your `launchSettings.json` file:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "MyProjectName": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7069;http://localhost:5042",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH": "/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The important part here is the line that sets the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable. You'll need to do something similar in your deployment environment too.

---

To get things working in the Rider test runner you'll probably have to change your `.sln.DotSettings` file. The easiest way to do this is to using the Rider UI. Go to *Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Unit Testing > Runner* and add the environment variable using the controls at the bottom of the dialog.

My `.sln.DotSettings` file ended up looking like this (but with horrible formatting):

```
<wpf:ResourceDictionary
    xml:space="preserve"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:ss="urn:shemas-jetbrains-com:settings-storage-xaml"
    xmlns:wpf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <s:String
        x:Key="/Default/Housekeeping/UnitTestingMru/UnitTestRunner/EnvironmentVariablesIndexed/=DYLD_005FLIBRARY_005FPATH/@EntryIndexedValue">/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib
    /s:String>
</wpf:ResourceDictionary>
```

---

To get tests working from the command line, I'd recommend adding a `.runsettings` file and referencing it from your `.csproj` file.

My `.runsettings` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
    <RunConfiguration>
        <EnvironmentVariables>
            <DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH>/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib</DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH>
        </EnvironmentVariables>
    </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

and my project file looks something like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <Authors>Dave Watts</Authors>
        ....
        <RunSettingsFilePath>$(ProjectDir).runsettings</RunSettingsFilePath>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: @user606521 does this answer you question?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of messing with env variables, just link it to defaultly searched location:

```bash
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/lib/libssl.3.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```

Comment: This seems to work pretty well. For me the paths were slightly different:

`ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib/libssl.3.dylib /usr/local/lib/`